# Can I create DataTable With Inline Action Buttons?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to create Datatable with Inline Action buttons. How do we place action buttons inside the Table , I mean each row. Almost similar to WordPress Posts Page. 
[image: Sample Image]
 I am not asking full code.  Just a sample code to begin writing it. Sofar I have the following code.

```
jQuery("#myTableID").dataTable({
    aoColumns : [{ "sClass": "center",
 "mRender": function (data, type, row) {      
  return '<div class="input-control checkbox" /> <label><input type="checkbox" name="reference" class="job_checkbox"  value="' + row[0] + '"> <span class="check"></span></label></div>'; }  , "sWidth": "1%" },            
  { "sWidth": "20%" }, 
  { "sWidth": "30%"},
  { "sWidth": "30%"}]
});
```

Actually I am not good at jQuery  and JS functions. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: i am waiting for some suggestions. if i get idea how to begin, let me try it on my own.

Comment: Someone help me. I don't have enough reputation to make it featured one.

Comment: What DataTables version are you using - 1.9 or 1.10?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option to produce content for specific cell.

For example:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
       targets: 0,
       render: function(data, type, full, meta){
          if(type === 'display'){
             data = data + '<div class="links">' +
                 '<a href="#">Edit</a> ' +
                 '<a href="#">Quick Edit</a> ' +
                 '<a href="#">Trash</a> ' +
                 '<a href="#">View</a>' +
                 '</div>';                     
          }

          return data;
       }
    }]
});
```

Using the following CSS rules you can show links only when user moves mouse over the row:

```css
#example tr .links {
    display:none;
}

#example tr:hover .links {
    display:block;   
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okd7f0wx/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Your answer is awesome. Thanks for your help.